# re-positioning text without it moving with browser

Tags: html, css

Having some issues with some basic stuff.
Created -

```html
<?php 
 include_once 'header.php';
?>

<section class="main-container">
<div class="main-wrapper">
 <h2>Home</h2>

</div>
</section>

<?php 
 include_once 'footer.php';
?>

<div class="awesome">
 <?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
   echo $_SESSION['u_uid'];
  }
?>
</div>
```

This

```html
<div class="awesome">
 <?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
   echo $_SESSION['u_uid'];
  }
?>
</div>
```

Just defines the users username upon sign-up.
However upon trying to scale it down using CSS it seems to jump over the page each time I scale down my browser, from either left or right down or up.

[example one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWeXK.png)

[example two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN8Se.png)

```html
.awesome {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry about the format of this message. Didn't turn out the way I intended.

Comment: Found the edit button, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put `awesome div` inside `main-wrapper`

```
<section class="main-container">
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <h2>Home</h2>
<div class="awesome">
    <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
            echo $_SESSION['u_uid'];
        }
?>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

or you can try to put in `main-container`

```
<section class="main-container">
    <div class="awesome">
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
                echo $_SESSION['u_uid'];
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <h2>Home</h2>

    </div>
    </section>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Upon doing so it stays in the same position. However, how would I go about making it move near the logout button - still making it static as it is now. I tried using margin-right:  60px; but it wouldn't budge. `.awesome {
    margin-right:  60px;
}`

Comment: Okay upon doing some experimenting. `.awesome {
    font-family: arial;
    padding-left: 85%;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #111;
}` Makes it goes to the side however [link](https://i.imgur.com/rSk5NIY.png) I can not move it upwards.

Comment: You can add `text-align: right` to make this near logo

Comment: Aligning it right isn't the issue. It is positioned correctly to the right at the [moment](https://i.imgur.com/rSk5NIY.png). However I can't simply push it up - which is now the issue. `.awesome {
    font-family: arial;
    padding-left: 85%;
    line-height: -20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #111;
}`

Comment: `<?php 
 include_once 'header.php';
?>

<section class="main-container">
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <h2>Home</h2>
<div class="awesome">
    <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
            echo $_SESSION['u_uid'];
        }
?>
</div>
</div>
</section>

<?php 
 include_once 'footer.php';
?>`

Comment: See my edit. I think `awesome` should be inside `main-container`

Comment: I applied the edit - how would I go ahead and move the username up using CSS? An issue also was created - upon shrinking down the browser horizontally it moved the username with it. See here https://i.imgur.com/tngAEGV.png VS https://i.imgur.com/8PaHVT2.png

Comment: I think you should test using inspect element and check the width of the menu. Because the menu is placed the different position, I just guess to fix for you.

Comment: I fixed it. `<?php 
 include_once 'header.php';
?>

 <div class="main-wrapper">
<section class="main-container">
    <div class="awesome">
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
                echo $_SESSION['u_uid'];
            }
        ?>
    </div>

    </div>
    </section>

<?php 
 include_once 'footer.php';
?>

<div class="home">
<h2>Home</h2>
</div>`

Comment: `.awesome {
    font-family: arial;
    padding-left: 85%;
    margin-top: -77px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #111;
}

.home {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #111;
    line-height: 50x;
    text-align: center;
}`

Comment: Remove the `padding-left: 85%;`. I think